# Hibernate GROUP BY invalid for Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, group-by

I created an Hibernate query like this:

```
select new ProjectForUser
  (p.projectId, p.name, p.description, p.client, p.startDate, p.endDate,
   p.liveDate, p.projectState, p.overallRagStatus, p.scopeRagStatus, p.flt,
   up.projectManager) 
from UserProjectAssociation up left join up.project p 
where up.user.id = :userId and up.project.projectState != 'ARCHIVED' 
group by p.projectId
```

to retrieve projects for user. Projects are stored in one table, users in the other and UserProjectAssociation is a joining table with additional attribute - projectManager.

The whole query works fine for H2 database, but on oracle I get this error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

What is a correct way to use GROUP BY for Oracle?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include other columns in group by clause which are  in select statement

Comment: That did the job, thanks!

Comment: it doesn't look like you're using an aggregate function in your select list; if all you're wanting to do is retrieve unique rows, then you need DISTINCT, i.e., `select distinct col1, col2, col3, ... from ...`. I assume this is possible to do in Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem. ORA-00979 occurs when the GROUP BY clause does not contain all the expressions in the SELECT clause. Any SELECT expression that is not included in the GROUP function must be listed in the GROUP BY clause. These are AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, and VARIANCE.

see: https://www.tekstream.com/resources/ora-00979-not-a-group-by-expression/